# php7_module on Homebrew LAMP install won't allow restart of apache through Mac terminal

Tags: macos, apache, terminal, homebrew

I am trying to restart apache in the terminal to fix an .htaccess problem I had in apache. I use 
`sudo apachectl restart` 
and then I receive this error 
`[so:warn] [pid 9807] AH01574: module php7_module is already loaded, skipping`
I have also tried `sudo apachectl stop` and receive the same error.

I learned it might work, by going into the httpd.conf file to comment out the php7_module as seen here

```
LoadModule setenvif_module libexec/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule version_module libexec/mod_version.so
#LoadModule remoteip_module libexec/mod_remoteip.so
#LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php71/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
#LoadModule proxy_module libexec/mod_proxy.so
#LoadModule proxy_connect_module libexec/mod_proxy_connect.so
#LoadModule proxy_ftp_module libexec/mod_proxy_ftp.so
```

and I have also commented out these three php7_module lines which are installed in the httpd.conf file with homebrew.

```
#LoadModule actions_module libexec/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module libexec/mod_alias.so
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/mod_rewrite.so
#LoadModule php7_module        /usr/local/Cellar/php71/7.1.5_17/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
#LoadModule php7_module        /usr/local/Cellar/php71/7.1.6_18/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
#LoadModule php7_module        /usr/local/Cellar/php71/7.1.7_19/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
```

Even then, this still did not fix the problem. Also tried using Homebrew tap services to restart Apache as seen here:
[image]

I need to restart Apache and the terminal is not allowing me because PHP7_Module is already loaded! Is there a file i'm forgetting to comment out? httpd.conf has had all four of the php7_modules commented out. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please copy/paste the text here instead of posting a screenshot.

Comment: What's the location of httpd.conf file you are editing?